# How to find missing term in AP

Tags: c

Actually I am new to C programming language. Can any one tell me where am I making mistake
every time I give input like

1 5 7 9 11 or 1 3 7 9 11

It give two outputs
Here is the code

```
main()
{
    int i,ino,flag=0;
    int ser[2500],dif[2499],fault[3];
    printf("Enter number of elements\n");
    scanf("%d",&ino);
    printf("Enter elements:\n");
    for(i=0;i<ino;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&ser[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<ino-1;i++)
    {
        dif[i]=ser[i+1]-ser[i];
    }

    for(i=0;i<ino-1;i++)
    {
        if(dif[i]==dif[i+1])
        flag++;
        else
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                if(dif[i]==dif[i+2])
                printf("Missing numbera is: %d\n",ser[i+1]+dif[i]);
                else
                printf("Missing numberb is: %d\n",ser[i]+dif[i+1]);
            }
            else
            {
                if(dif[i]==dif[i-1])
                printf("Missing numberc is: %d\n",ser[i+1]+dif[i]);
                else if(dif[i+1]==dif[i-1])
                printf("Missing numberd is: %d\n",ser[i]+dif[i+1]);
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag==(ino-2))
    printf("no term missing");

}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? Use a debugger, single-step through your program, and compare the contents of the variables with what you expect ...

Comment: whats the purpose of this program

Comment: Finding missing terms in an arithmetic progression -- the title sas it all..

Comment: It gives two outputs because `dif[j]` is detected twice. First time when `i=j-1`, second time when `i=j`. Just remove one print out of two and the output will be correct (if there is no consecutive mistakes in your ap).

Comment: @xtofpernod not sure if you're sarcastic....

Comment: Actually its better to use return in each if block. @francis thanks man that was really very helpful but i still have a doubt.
for example i have dif array having elements 4,2,2,2 then i have i=0 but for that why the control is going to the else, where i!=0, it should go to if(dif[i]==dif[i+1]).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool has_missing_term(int arr[], int size, int *x){
    int i, d = (arr[size-1] - arr[0])/(size-1);
    int n;
    bool ok = true;
    for(n=arr[0], i=1; i < size ; ++i){
        n += d;
        if(n != arr[i]){
            ok = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(ok)
        return false;
    d = (arr[size-1] - arr[0])/size;
    for(n=arr[0], i=1; i < size ; ++i){
        n += d;
        if(n != arr[i]){
            *x = n;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;//What happened?
}

int main(){
    int i, ino, x;
    int ser[2500];
    printf("Enter number of elements\n");
    scanf("%d",&ino);
    printf("Enter elements:\n");
    for(i=0;i<ino;i++)
        scanf("%d",&ser[i]);
    if(has_missing_term(ser, ino, &x))
        printf("Missing numbera is: %d\n", x);
    else
        printf("no term missing");

}
```